# Responsive design not working on iphone

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

My first responsive project and it's not as smooth as I hoped!

I've completed an initial concept with break points at 768 and 480 and it breaks fine when I resize in the browser. I did a final test in my smart phone and I get the FULL SITE!

I've been banging my head against the wall and I sure hope somebody can bail me out!

You can see the page here - www.siphon-marketing.com/unifirst

Also, when resizing my screen on a desktop, it breaks OK but I need to refresh at each point to force some elements in place...any way I can prevent that?

Thanks SO much!

Comment: Is this supposed to be in there? <meta name="viewport" content="width=960">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there were TWO viewports...one overriding the other

Answer (score 1):

Use the meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

See [here](http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/01/device-width-and-how-not-to-hate-your.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your media query, you've defined your `.container width` and `.header width` as 100%.  I'm not positive on this, but I think this is what's happening.  Your `.container` is initially set to `width: 1000px;`.  At this point, your mobile device is seeing this as a desktop-focused webpage.  Mobile browsers all have different functionality when rendering large webpages.  Some will try to reflow text to fit your screen (while other elements are in normal desktop position), some will zoom the page out to fit the whole width on its viewport, and others will not do anything with it, so you will have to pan and zoom around the whole page.

Media queries are good for forcing responsive designs at different sized viewports.  These styles override those originals outside of the media query, however if the mobile browser thinks that the page is 1000px wide initially it will "expand" to 1000px.  If your media query  overrides that to say 100%, the browser might be treating that as meaning "100% of 1000px".

Try defining a pixel width in your media query and see if that helps.  If this is accurate, I wonder if in your media query you could say something like:

```
.container {
  width: 480px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Again, I've not tested this, but the idea sounds like it might work.  I'd be interested to see if this helps though, so if you try it, comment back and let me know.  Thanks!